# What are good methods to attach glass to wood?

Tags: wood, glass, adhesives

I'm a woodworker and I really like turning.  While I've made some beautiful goblets on my lathe, I'm always a little leery about recommending them for actual drinking.  On top of that many of them do crack because of flaws in the wood.

However, I've seen where people will buy fairly cheap wine glasses and cut the stem off, and attach them to some hand turned base.  This can look nice and opens up a host of possibilities.  However, I don't know the what method would work to hold the two materials together securely.  Epoxy?

Comment: My first thought was epoxy as well. Not sure what else you would use.

Comment: A food-safe sealant like Dap 00688 Household Waterproof Adhesive would be my recommendation. But why not a wooden goblet? Cutting boards are made from wood. Fancy salad bowls are made from wood. And I am fairly sure humans have been drinking booze from wooden cups for thousands of years. Didn't you see Indian Jones and the Last Crusade?

Answer (score 5):

Epoxies are the essential answer to your question.

Since you are affixing two materials that can expand or contract quote a bit, you need to choose an epoxy that will not shrink and risk cracking the glass.  The wood should be ok.

From here, the answer would turn into a bevy of brand recommendations.  I think you should look for what is available to you, and decide one that matches your 'mechanical properties', color, hardening process, etc.

I have used "Acraglas" for a nearly-identical purpose.  It only comes in brown color, from what I know.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend 3M VHB tape. We used to use it to bond wood Muntins to glass when building custom door units. It is extremely strong, has a peel and stick adhesive, and because it is essentially a thin layer of foam, it will not be a problem with any slight wood movement.

http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/Adhesives/Tapes/Applications/~/Bonding-Muntin-Bars-to-Glass?N=8639921+3294737254&rt=rud